# seperate redis cluster from one stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, elastic-cache

I have a `Redis Cluster` which was created by using `aws-cdk(python)`. Basically i created this `redis-cluster` as a part of `service-stack`

my **service-stack** looks like below

```
s3 bucket
ecs cluster
lambda function
redis cluster
```

I want to seperate `redis cluster` from `service-stack` and want to place in another stack like `redis-stack`

**Possible solution**
I need to remove `redis cluster` from `service-stack` and create an another stack called `redis-stack` and deploy my `redis cluster`

**Issue**
My `redis cluster` is already deployed in `PROD`. I dont want to delete `redis cluster`

**Goal**
without deleting existing `redis cluster`, I want to move the `redis cluster` from `service-stack` to `redis-stack`

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is possible to do it through [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) procedure as explained in [Moving resources between stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html).

However, `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster` **does not support** import procedure. Only [some resources support it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html). Sadly, ElastiCache is not one of these resources.

So if you don't want to touch your prod cluster, for now you are stuck with what you have. Maybe in a near future support for importing, and subsequently moving `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster` will be added to CloudFormation. Otherwise you would have to snapshot it, and recreated in a new stack.

Comment: i didnt get it. Can you please explain "snapshot it, and recreated in a new stack" ?

Comment: @siva Basically create a new cluster from backup, using [SnapshotArns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#cfn-elasticache-cachecluster-snapshotarns). You would have to test this procedure on some dummy cluster to get the feel of it and understand how it works before you attempt it on prod cluster.

Comment: @siva Here are [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html) about backup and resotore.

Comment: Thnaks @marcin for your help